While Identifying Transistor terminals with Multimeter diode mode, why does B-E junction yields a slightly higher forward voltage then B-C junction?
I've learned that multimeter produces a small current in the diode mode and then measures the voltage drop across the diode. So a high resistance should produce a high voltage difference.
Since emitter base junction produces a higher voltage so it means that it has a high resistance than base collector junction.
But, since the emitter is heavily doped and base emitter depletion region is smaller, it should have a large number of charge carriers. And so it should offer a lower resistance then collector.
Why then the base emitter has higher voltage drop than the base collector in the multimeter?

Resistance is, generally, the wrong way to be thinking about things when learning about diodes. There is a resistive term in the full model, but the idealized diode junction itself obeys the Shockley diode equation instead, acting nothing like a resistor at all.

Consider the structure of a practical npn BJT:

(image source: Wikipedia
Notice the collector region is physically larger than the emitter region, and the BC junction has a bigger area than the BE junction. So even if you do think of these devices as a kind of resistor, it makes sense that the one with the larger cross-sectional area should have lower resistance.

But, since the emitter is heavily doped and base emitter depletion region is smaller, it should have a large number of charge carriers.

The emitter being heavily doped also means its Fermi level is shifted further from the intrinsic level. This means the built in potential between the emitter and the base is higher if the emitter is more strongly doped than the collector. And this built-in potential is the barrier that has to be overcome before current can flow through the junction, so it is closely related to the voltage you read on your multimeter when you measure the diode drop of this junction. 
